# Import .pde file on PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, export, import

How can I import my .pde file which I already exported from another database by PL/SQL Developer?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not mentioned in the documention.

You can import it via `Tools > Import Tables`